# #1054 - Unknown column in 'field list' Is minus sign a special character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

Trying to insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_check`(`id_product`, `name`, `catalog`)     
VALUES  (30767,'CT39-235126','79926330')
```

The error is

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'CT39' in 'field list'
```

Why does it think CT39 is supposed to be a column when it is (a part) of a value? How to get around this error?

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with the code posted. It executes OK on my end.

Comment: Works also on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2917).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your query and it works very fine.

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_check`(`id_product`, `name`, `catalog`)     
VALUES  (30767,'CT39-235126','79926330')
```

It is possible that you have placed other quotes (backticks) in the query executed.

If I change the quotes like

```
INSERT INTO `ps_product_check`(`id_product`, `name`, `catalog`)     
VALUES  (30767,`CT39-235126`,'79926330')
```

I get the same error.

Comment: I am so sorry. It was my own stupidity: on line 39 out of 200 there was a CT 39 without any quotes at all, which caused the error.